# What's the inner width of my rim?

Tags: tire, wheels, rims

I just measured the inner width of my rim with a ruler and it seemed to be a hair over 14mm.  Looking at [the tire sizing chart on Sheldon Brown's site](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#width) it doesn't have an entry for 14mm inner width rims. My wheels are Vuelta Corsa HDs (nashbar special), and that rim is probably used on other Vuelta wheels, so I'm thinking it's not an unusual size. Might they be considered 15mm? Anyone know the official spec for those rims?

Comment: I think a picture of the rim with a ruler on it will be helpful.

Comment: Are there any labels on the rim?  14-15mm is certainly believable, and 1mm difference isn't significant.

Comment: You should probably using something within the 13-15mm widths on the charts in this case - the problem is really with running a fat tire on a narrow rim or a narrow tire on a fat rim - the problem exists, but is unlikely to be significant in practice as the type of bike usually determines the type of tires good enough (like, you're not going to run a 25c tire on a Surly Karate Monkey, or a 29x2.5 on a racer - they won't fit to begin with, and even if they did, it wouldnt make sense given the rest of the bike).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nashbar's specs for the rim list the inner width as 16mm.
http://www.nashbar.com/bikes/Product_10053_10052_566766_-1___
(click the "Specs" link)

This is a fairly standard width for road wheels, so you should be able to safely run any common road tire size (21mm-35mm give or take a few mm).